# Running Matlab M-function from Python

Tags: python, matlab, operating-system, subprocess, matlab-deployment

I want to run my Matlab function `(test.m)` from Python. I converted the function to an exe file `test.exe` using `mcc -m` command of Matlab; and I can run it `test.exe` from command prompt of windows.

On the other side, when I run exe files using os.system and subprocess.call by Python, it works well:

`subprocess.call('C:\Program Files\DVD Maker\DVDMaker.exe',shell=True)`

(My DVDMaker opens)

But when I run
`subprocess.call('C:\...\test.exe',shell=True)`

I receive this:
`The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Answer (score 1):

Your string handling is wrong.

Instead of

```
'C:\...\test.exe'
```

either use

```
'C:\\...\\test.exe'
```

or

```
r'C:\...\test.exe'
```

or even

```
'C:/.../test.exe'
```

which will work as well.

IOW, in your original string, the part `\test` is recognized as <`TAB` character> + `'est'`. You must quote the `\` with another `\`, use `r`aw strings which don't care about the funny `\` stuff inside or omit the `\`s altogether by replacing them with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

1. You did not install MCR.
2. Not running as administrator
3. Running from network drive